# TOTP radius server for Citrix XenApp

Tags: citrix, google-authenticator, netscaler

I'm looking for astandards-based TOTP (time-based one time password) authentication server to implement strong security for my Netscaler appliance. 
I was not able to find a radius server with easy to use interface that supports Google Authenticator. 
Grateful if you can suggest a solution!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how easy to use [this solution](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX132808) is, but what Citrix suggests is OpenOTP. It supports Google Authenticator (in addition to others). It is free for 25 users, 50 users will [cost](https://www.rcdevs.com/store/product/view/1) you at least 1000EUR

Another solution is [TOTPRadius](https://token2.com/?content=totpradius), no pricing info is available, but it is the only one supporting self-registration if using Citrix StoreFront.

p.s. Sorry, forgot to add a disclaimer: I am affiliated with Token2

Answer (score 0):

Update regarding OpenOTP: it is free for 40 users. Please ask RCDevs for actual pricing regarding more users.

Starting with 50 users you are entiteled to install the OpenOTP/WebADM Backend as an active/active cluster (2 servers).

The [OpenOTP Token App](https://www.rcdevs.com/solutions/tokens/software/) supports additional features compared to Google Authenticator.

For fast evaluation, virtual appliances (for Oracle Virtual Box or VMware) are available under [here](https://www.rcdevs.com/downloads/VMWare+Appliances/).

Answer (score 0):

Protectimus provides 2FA solution for strong protection against unauthorized account access within Citrix XenApp. It also has a status of [Citrix Ready](https://citrixready.citrix.com/protectimus-solutions-llp/protectimus.html). You can contact sales team for actual pricing.

Disclaimer: I work for Protectimus